# Light doesn't cast shadows!

Tags: light, shadows

I have a problem. I wanted to cast shadow on a cube. So I created a new file and added plane like this.[image] Why doesn't the point cast shadow on cube?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently in *solid* mode and not in the *render preview*. The former uses a simple shader and no path tracing is applied.

**Solid Mode**
[image: Solid Mode]

**Render Preview**
[image: Render Preview]

If you press <kbd>F12</kbd> or use *Render > Render Image* you will see that the lamp casts a shadow in the final render as well.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about it!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.